# plinq select count where all functions evaluate true

Tags: .net, plinq

I have a set of data all doubles:
100 rows 20 columns

I’m pulling the data into a IEnumerable list with:

```
var RowsOfData = File.ReadLines(dll.Globals.OutputDir +     dll.Globals.filename).Select(a => a.Split(',').ToList());

var FilteredRowsToday = (from n in RowsOfData
       where n[1] == 1
       orderby n[0] descending
       select n);
```

I then have a set of functions, which do simple check on each the data rows and each returns a Bool.
What I want is a count of the number of rows for which each of the functions evaluated true.
And then when I scale my project up I want this processed asap in parallel if possible, I’ve tried:

```
foreach (var row in FilteredRowsToday) {  
is f1() true, is f2() true 
etc
}
```

Seems slow
I’ve tried to do in parallel

```
foreach (var row in FilteredRowsToday.AsParallel())
```

no faster

I’m now thinking something like:

```
var TotalTrue = FilteredRowsToday.Select(item => f1() & f2() & f3()).Count();
```

I can pre-process the data to provide the results of the evaluations of each function as a sort of binary grid if that’s a better stating point?

```
F1, f2, f3 etc
1, 0, 0 row 1
1, 1, 1 row 2 etc
```

suggestions welcome!

Comment: 100 rows is a very small count. Why is your computation so slow? Do some of the methods take a long time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just interested in the count where all three functions evaluate to true, then this should be sufficient:

```
var TotalTrue = FilteredRowsToday.Count(item => f1() & f2() & f3());
```

As for why it's slow, your functions could be the reason behind this.

You could try only evaluating the rows until either all three functions return true, or at least one of them return false, e.g.

```
var TotalTrue = FilteredRowsToday.Count(item => f1() && f2() && f3());
```

I.e. If `f1()` evaluates to `false`, then don't bother doing the rest of the validations.

**UPDATE:** If your functions aren't doing any resource-intensive checks, then parallel LINQ won't do you much good (more info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997399.aspx)).

Comment: Tobias, et al, many thanks, I did have a list to check the return of each function which I checked in this manner: bool AllConditionsTrue = conditions.TrueForAll(o => o); which worked fine, but I like yours above too.  As to the relative expense of the computation of each function: early days, some functions are real simple, other more complex, thats why I may pre-process the functions first and then count the results from a binary grid type structure as a seperate process.

Comment: @user1796185: Preprocessing won't speed up your process if that is where most of the processing time goes into. Counting the results isn't the problem. My suggestion would be to focus on your evaluation methods to see where you can optimise them. You could possibly even evaluate them in order of complexity when you check your results, thus ensuring that the cheap (fast) methods are run first and you only run the more intensive ones if the others evaluate to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

As I see you are reading file at once and it's a kind of comma separated file.
If you would yield the records from file as you read, it will allow you to process them until you are waiting for the next read.

```
private IEnumerable<string> GetRecords(string fileName) {
    using (StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(fileName))
            {
                string line = reader.ReadLine();
                while (line != null)
                {   
                   yield return line.Split(',');
                   line = reader.ReadLine();
                 }
             }
}
```

You are also spending some time on converting the result of `Split` into `List` which is already an  `array` and has index access needed to perform the query.

I would also advice to apply optimizations suggested before like using `.Count(item => f1() & f2() & f3());` instead of `.Select(item => f1() & f2() & f3()).Count();`.

Nevertheless I do not believe any of this optimizations will bring any improvement with such a small amount of data. I think we can help you better if you post some details about you processing portion of code.